# Change the type of User ID to UUID

Tags: python, django

I'm using `User` model from `django.contrib.auth.models`, the default id(primary_key) type is int, how to change it to UUID?, for example `id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use AbstractUser model if you need changes in the default user model.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Then in your `settings.py`,

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: How you solve the error which throws in the admin site when the django tries to write some log to the `django_admin_log` table which refers to the user's integer id?

`operator does not exist: integer = uuid
LINE 1: ...OIN "users_user" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "users_u...`

Comment: I also am getting `ProgrammingError at /admin/
operator does not exist: integer = uuid LINE 1: ...JOIN "core_user" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "core_us...`. Did you ever solve?

Answer (score 0):

If you had already executed any migrations before making the UUID change, it is crucial to delete the tables and recreate the migrations.