# Django Rest Framework - IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django, want to create custom user models as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models

class UniservedTeam(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Role = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=1000), blank=True,null=True)
    ContactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In shell I am trying to create an user :

```
>>> user = User.objects.create(email='piyush@uniserved.com',password='Piyush@123',username='Piyush@24',last_name='Wanare',first_name='Piyush',is_active=True)
>>> user
<User: Piyush@24>
>>> user.id
1
>>> team = UniservedTeam.objects.create(id=user.id,Role=['Vendor Co-ordinator'],ContactNumber='862339798167')
```

Getting Error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 700, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 728, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 812, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 851, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1060, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/piyush/.environments/awsd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Try `user = user` when you create your new `team` instead of setting the `id`.

Comment: @MattCremeens Can you write the correct query?

Comment: @MattCremeens, Thanks it works

Comment: OK. Added the entire thing for you as an answer. Glad it worked.

Comment: maybe there is wrong data in your database....try deleting the corrupt data and creating the user again.....

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want instead after you make your `user` is this

```
team = UniservedTeam.objects.create(user=user,Role=['Vendor Co-ordinator'],ContactNumber='862339798167')
```

Comment: Do you know, how do I change user_id field as an uuid field?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the name of the `id` field?

Comment: No, now type of the user_id field is Integer I want to change it into uuid field.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311048/change-the-type-of-user-id-to-uuid) and see if it helps.

Comment: No actually it adds one more field as Id in custom model with uuid type.

Comment: Have you tried it? It looks like it will actually change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144363/discussion-between-piyush-s-wanare-and-matt-cremeens).

Comment: Chat is blocked on this computer. You may want to make a new question anyway as that is what this is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
team = UniservedTeam.objects.create(user__id=user.id, Role=['Vendor Co-ordinator'],ContactNumber='862339798167')
```